# ArrayList not working as expected in do..while loop

Tags: java, string, arraylist, do-while

I have the following loop which creates a String which fits exactly in a screen, it creates a page so to speak.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < totalLine; i++) {

        temp = enterLine(mTextView, textToBeShown, i);
            full = full + temp;

    }
```

So after the iteration is done `full` holds one page.

What i want to do is create an outer iteration which allows me to create more than one page, the amount of pages to be created isn't defined. So the iteration needs to stop if there aren't more pages to be created.

I tried the following code but for some reason when calling a page `Pages.get(1)` it gives out the whole String not just the `full` / Page. For Example if i three strings have been added to the `ArrayList` **Pages** there will be three Strings in the `ArrayList` but all with the same value.

With some testing with the `Log`, i know that the first iteration is working well, and that `full` gives the expected values meaning in the first `do` iteration gives out the expected values to the `full` so does the second iteration etc..

```
    do{
    for (int i = 0; i < totalLine; i++) {

        temp = enterLine(mTextView, textToBeShown, i);
        if(temp.trim().length() == 0){
            break;
        }else{
            full = full + temp;
        }
    }
    Pages.add(full);
```

So the question is what am i doing wrong with the `ArrayList` and why isn't it working as I'm expecting.

**Edit**

This is the `enterLine` code: More `Log`'s were used didn't feel the need the display them all.

```
public String enterLine(TextView mTextView, String textBeShown, int i){

        String A;
        int number = mTextView.getPaint().breakText(textToBeShown, 0, textToBeShown.length(),true,mTextView.getWidth(), null);

        if(textToBeShown.substring(number-1,number) != " "){
            number = textToBeShown.substring(0,number).lastIndexOf(" ");
            Log.e("TAG1", "Found " + i);
        }

        A = (textToBeShown.substring(0, number) + "\n");
        Log.e(TAG, textToBeShown.substring(0, number));
        textToBeShown = textToBeShown.substring(number, textToBeShown.length());
        return A;
    }
```

Comment: post the code for `enterLine`, not sure what that is doing...

Comment: I will, but the `enterLine` works correctly, altough it can be connected to it.

Comment: You need to re-initialize `full` to an empty value somewhere, no? You keep filling it. Would it be a good idea to reset it bewteen `do` and `for`?

Comment: Where is the `while` for the `do`?  Also, have `full` be a `StringBuilder`, not a `String`.

Comment: Not completely related to your question but it's better practice to use a StringBuilder when you build up a String over a loop like that.

Comment: **Class Stacker** Thanks, silly mistake

Comment: **Eric Jablow** , **phoenix 7360** I will look into StringBuilder, will it create a problem if later i wish to convert full into a SpannableString?

Comment: **Eric Jablow** About the while i will add a bit to this question because i still have a problem with it and currently I'm only experimenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do{
    full=""
    for (int i = 0; i < totalLine; i++) {
        temp = enterLine(mTextView, textToBeShown, i);
        if(temp.trim().length() == 0){
            break;
        }else{
            full = full + temp;
        }
    }
    Pages.add(full);
}while(...)
```

or better

```
do{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < totalLine; i++) {
        temp = enterLine(mTextView, textToBeShown, i));
        if(temp.trim().length() == 0){
            break;
        }else{
            builder.append(temp);
        }
    }
    Pages.add(builder.toString());
}while(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, it's not your arraylist but your loop. Add adds an element to the arraylist, get(index) gets the index'th element from the list. No problem there.

Your problem is that it adds full to the page after the loop, by which point full already contains everything. Put the pages.add inside the loop and it'll be fixed. Make sure you reset full each iteration. Put full = "" at the start of the loop. Should work then.

Comment: I'm sorry it may be my fault that i didn't explain it well, but when i goes from 0 till `totalLine` it creates one `full` page. than in the `do..while` it creates the pages. In each of the `for..loop`'s iteration a line that fits the width of the screen is being created.

Comment: Ah. Well then you'll still want to reinitialize full at the start of each loop, as it is it's just going to keep collecting all the text into one string and adding ever longer strings to pages. Try that, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yes, someone had already suggested it and it worked thanks for the help!

Comment: I did in the original post as well, "Put full = "" at the start of the loop". But I'm glad you got it working